# PCs connected to the same wireless network are assigned with IPs of different subnets. How can I make them assigned with IPs in one subnet?

Tags: networking, subnet, vlan

There are two PCs, PC1 and PC2, connected to the same wireless network. They are assigned with IPs of different subnets.

- PC1's IP address is 10.10.10.123, with gateway 10.10.10.1.
- PC2's IP address is 10.10.20.234, with gateway 10.10.20.1.
- Running `tracert www.stackoverflow.com`:

  - Line 1 is gateway. That is 10.10.10.1 for PC1, and 10.10.20.1 for PC2.
  - Line 2 is the same, which is "time exceeds".
  - Line 3 is the same, which is an IP address of local telecom company, say 111.122.133.1.

As a result, PC1 cannot ping PC2 and vice versa.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to switch PC1 to PC2's subnet by making some configurations on PC1?
2. Or is there any method to force PC1 get a new address as if it were connected to this network for the first time? Since it seems that the IP of a PC is assigned randomly for the first time, and remains the same when connected again.
3. Or is there any other method to make PC1 able to ping PC2 except configuring exchange or router (they cannot be accessed by me) and tunnelling via a host (that would be another question about tunnelling two inner networks)?

I will keep completing the description of my question if any further details are needed. Thanks in advance for any suggestions or comments on solutions.

Comment: do you have 2 dhcp on the same network ?

Comment: yes, dhcp host is the same as gateway, that is, 10.10.10.1 and 10.10.20.1 @Vidal

Comment: why do you want 2 DHCP server on the same segment ?

Comment: Actually PC1 and PC2 gets different ip segment, gateway and dhcp host when they are first connected to the network. Maybe there are several vlans, or some other design in this network, i don't know. What i want is to make PC1 and PC2 get ip address of the same segment. Then of course, they use the same dhcp host. @Vidal